# python: How can I test my database model using in-memory db?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, alembic

I am developing a project in `Flask` and using `SQLAlchemy` as ORM
I have a `User` model as

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # noinspection PyShadowingBuiltins
    uuid = Column('uuid', GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                  unique=True)
    email = Column('email', String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    _password = Column('password', String, nullable=False)
    created_on = Column('created_on', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        default=datetime.utcnow())
    last_login = Column('last_login', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        onupdate=datetime.utcnow())
```

- I create a migration script using [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#tutorial).
- My database of choice is `PostgreSQL` but to test my models I preferred to use `SQLite` to make tests faster
- Problem came in when there are some types in `PostgreSQL` and not in `SQLite`, in this case `UUID`
- When I run migration on `sqlite://`, it gives me error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GUID'

**Question**
- How can I keep my schema with `GUID` and run in-memory tests with SQLite? seems like `SQLite` doesn't have anything like it
- What are some ways people run tests faster(in-memory) when their database is `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not a good practice to mix database backends for testing, development and release. See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716847/sqlalchemy-sqlite-for-testing-and-postgresql-for-development-how-to-port and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685899/schema-qualified-tables-with-sqlalchemy-sqlite-and-postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

How comes the tests faster with SQLite?

Anyway, if you want to keep things in memory...well, so keep your database in memory.
Actually PostgreSQL moves frequently accessed data to memory, but anyway, you can install some RAMFS/RAMHDD solution and put your database there, so it will be extremely fast

You can google for solutions "postgresql on ramdisk"