# SQLalchemy order_by hybrid_property resulting in "No such table"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My main goal is to make multiple filter options for a Car class.
I can easily filter by distance and by the construction year, as they are just attributes of the class.
The Car class is related to the Review class by a one-to-many relationship (One car can have many reviews). These reviews have a star rating from 0 - 5. I want to sort the Cars by the average rating of their reviews.

This is where I am at so far:
The classes:

```
class Cars(db.Model):
    __tablename__= "Cars"
    
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    distance = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # Some other attributes

    reviews = db.relationship('Reviews', backref='car')
    

    @hybrid_property                  
    def score(self):
        if len(self.reviews) != 0:
            return sum(review.stars for review in self.reviews) / len(self.reviews)
        else:
            return None

    @score.expression
    def score(cls):
        return (select([func.count(Reviews.id)]).select_from(Reviews).where(Reviews.car_id == cls.id))
        

class Reviews(db.Model):
    __tablename__= "Reviews"
    __bind_key__ = 'Reviews'

    # Some other attributes
    
    stars = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    car_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Cars.id'))
```

This is my view function:

```
@mainRoutes.route("/cars/<int:page_num>")
def cars(page_num):
    cars = getPagination(Cars, page = page_num, sort=Cars.score) #Cars.score can be swapped to other columns  
    return render_template("cars.html", cars=cars)
```

*I know that the score.expression function doesnt return the average, but instead the count. Thats just a WIP. For now, I just want to get this to work.*

This is the getPagination function I wrote:

```
    def getPagination(model, sort, perPage = 16, page = 1, **filter):
        return model.query.filter(**filter).order_by(sort).paginate(per_page = perPage, page = page)
```

When I try to sort the cars by the hybrid_property score, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Reviews
[SQL: SELECT "Cars".id AS "Cars_id", "Cars".model AS "Cars_model", "Cars".year AS "Cars_year", "Cars".distance AS "Cars_distance", "Cars".start_rent_period AS "Cars_start_rent_period", "Cars".end_rent_period AS "Cars_end_rent_period", "Cars".is_available AS "Cars_is_available" 
FROM "Cars" ORDER BY (SELECT count("Reviews".id) AS count_1 
FROM "Reviews" 
WHERE "Reviews".car_id = "Cars".id)
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (16, 0)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

The error originates from line:
`return model.query.filter(**filter).order_by(sort).paginate(per_page = perPage, page = page)`
If you want the full traceback, I can supply that.

**So my question is this:**
Why does Flask, or SQLalchemy, not recognize the Reviews table. Cause its definetly there. I can display instances of it, I can read and write values into it and everywhere else in the code it works fine.

**Other things I have tried:**
I took the code for the hybrid_property from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836076/sqlalchemy-order-by-hybrid-property-that-references-relationship) And also tried it with the provided answer, but `return select(Reviews.stars).where(Reviews.car_id==cls.id)` also didnt work

I suspected, that maybe the problem is, that some cars dont have reviews (which some cars definitely dont have) and tried to account for that in this approach: `reviews = select(case(exists().where(Reviews.car_id==cls.id), func.sum(Reviews.stars)))` , however I am very new to SQLalchemy and dont even know if my idea here makes sense. It surely didnt fix my issue though.

**Edit:**
The Cars database doesnt have a bind key, because its the "first" database.
Here are the settings I use for my Flask project:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///../Databases/Cars.db'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'Reviews':          'sqlite:///../Databases/Reviews.db',
    }
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb The Cars database is the "first" database, meaning it doesnt need a bind key. I can add that part in my question too.
Yeah, I call create_all() and I know that it works, because I can fetch data from the reviews database everywhere else in the code. I just tried it specifically with the bind argument that they use in the link you shared, but it didnt work.

Thanks a lot for your quick response :D

Comment: Maybe the schema needs to be specified on the fk (and perhaps elsewhere, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612971/flask-sqlalchemy-trouble-joining-tables-from-two-databases-different-bind-keys)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb After adding ```__table_args__ = {'schema':'Reviews'}``` to the Reviews class and doing the equivalent to the Cars class, I get the error ```sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'Reviews.car_id' could not find table 'Cars' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'```.
After modifying the ForeignKey field of Reviews to Cars.Cars.id, I get the error "No such table: Cars.Cars"
This seems like an endless rabbit hole

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that while binds enable to connecting to different databases, they don't enable combining classes with different binds in a single query.  For example, even a simple join will raise  `no such table: Reviews`

```py
Cars.query.options(orm.joinedload(Cars.reviews)).first().reviews
```

The usual way to handle this is by declaring a *schema*, at least on the "foreign" models:

```py
class Reviews(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Reviews'
    __bind_key__ = 'Reviews'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'reviews'}
```

Additionally we need to make SQLite aware of this; this can be done with an event listener (credit to [Gabriel Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13798424/gabriel-costa) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71022577/5320906)).

```py
# This should be executed before dropping/creating tables
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
...
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    dbapi_connection.execute('ATTACH "so71960014-reviews.db" AS "reviews"')
```

With these changes in place, the generated SQL qualifies the table name so that it is found:

```sql
SELECT "Cars".id AS "Cars_id", "Cars".year AS "Cars_year", "Cars".distance AS "Cars_distance" 
FROM "Cars" ORDER BY (SELECT count(reviews."Reviews".id) AS count_1 
FROM reviews."Reviews" 
WHERE reviews."Reviews".car_id = "Cars".id)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.
Unfortunately, I dont have time to implement this idea before the project deadline (26.4.), because so far I didnt even use these engines. After seeing them everywhere online though, I will definitely check them out and will also try to implement your solution.
I really appreciate you taking the time to dig into this issue :D